# Bayesian Perceptron - how can I generate many different perceptrons?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, neural-networks, bayesian-network

I am going to implement the Bayesian version of a perceptron that I read in the Statistical Mechanics of learning, by Engel-Van Den Broeck.

The idea to improve the performance is to use many Gibbs perceptrons J to define a golden one using their center of mass $J^\beta$. Formally:

$$J^\beta = \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt N \frac{\sum^M_{i=1}J^{(i)}}{\sqrt{(\sum^M_{i=1}J^{(i)})^2}}.$$

The problem is: how should I compute these many $J$? Should I just use many different initial condition? Should I use different $J$ taken during different epochs of the perceptron learning (this in particular is my thought)? Should I perturb data? Should I perturb one specific $J$ in many different random ways?